# Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by NOT be displayed with E_ALL error_reporting

Tags: php, macos

I don't have output buffering on AND display_errors is On and error_reporing is E_ALL, but on my server a php warning is not displayed.

The warning I am expecting is:

`Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by " when it is expected.`

The server that is not displaying the error is Mac OS X php 5.4.24. The server that IS displaying the cent os php 5.3.27. Both have E_ALL error reporting

Code that should cause error on both servers:

```
echo json_encode(array('success'=>true,'message'=>$success_message,'person_id'=>$employee_id,'redirect_code'=>$redirect_code));
$this->session->set_flashdata('manage_success_message', $success_message);
```

My question is:

Why am I NOT getting warning from my Mac OS X machine; but am getting a warning from cent os. The php versions are slightly different, but I wouldn't think this behavior would change.

Answer (score 1):

I modified the following in php.ini and was able to get the problem to happen on my mac server:

FROM:

```
output_buffering = 4096
```

TO:

```
output_buffering = Off
```

This seems to be the problem.

Comment: Glad you got it working! Make sure to accept your own answer so others will know :)

Answer (score 0):

Check for a single space, carriage return or tab before the opening `<?php` tag.

On both machines, try confirming your theory about error reporting settings with:

`echo ini_get ( 'display_errors' );`

If the environments on both your Mac and your CentOS machine are not *identical* in configuration, there are many plausible reasons for the difference... from error suppression to the way the OS handles EOL characters.

Comment: also check for a space, newline, etc before the opening or after the closing tag in any include files.

Comment: I have verified that display errors returns 1 and error_reporting is E_ALL

Comment: I got other notices + warnings, just not this specific one

Comment: So the problem is (probably) not that the warning is suppressed, but that it is not triggered at all... so the real question is why does CentOS already have data output before session headers, when MacOS does not.

Comment: I tried on another cent os server running php 5.3.28. It does NOT display the error either when it should. I have check all the files for single space or carriage return before the opening php. This is very odd

Comment: I am using Codeigniter if this makes any difference